# “2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64” in XCode 9

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, xcode9

Recently I upgraded my components (Cordova, node.js, Ionic, etc.) on my Windows 10 computer and on my Mac in order to be (more or less) up-to-date.

Using Visual Studio 2015 on a different PC I am developing a hybrid mobile app, which can be built when it comes to Android.

However in regards to iOS when I start `remotebuild --secure false` on my Mac and try deploying the files from my Windows PC it finally fails with the following error to be seen in build.log on my Mac in detail as following:

`duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/Joey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY-FAMOUS-APP-aeghcglepsoouoeuminlbzuvljeu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MY-FAMOUS-APP.build/Debug-iphoneos/MY-FAMOUS-APP.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/Joey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY-FAMOUS-APP-aeghcglepsoouoeuminlbzuvljeu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVLogger in:
    /Users/Joey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY-FAMOUS-APP-aeghcglepsoouoeuminlbzuvljeu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MY-FAMOUS-APP.build/Debug-iphoneos/MY-FAMOUS-APP.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVLogger.o
    /Users/Joey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY-FAMOUS-APP-aeghcglepsoouoeuminlbzuvljeu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVLogger.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I read a lot about possible solutions doing some crazy things in XCode, which are not targeting my problem: I write code only in Visual Studio using Angular.JS, Cordova and Ionic and want to enable an automatic setting in either of the files written in Visual Studio on my PC. Maybe a hook as described [here](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html) would work, but I do not know what and how to write.

However if no solution for Visual Studio 2015 is possible, I would be happy to receive hints in what to change in XCode 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/08/ios-release.html :

> **Important!** If you have included `cordova-plugin-console` in your project, you **must remove** it, otherwise your project will not build.

This caused my local build to fail. Not sure if this problem is yours aswell, but you can always try to remove it?

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console
```

And try to build again?

Comment: Note that (because of cache issues maybe?) I had to clean the project before successfully building. `cordova clean`, `cordova platform rm android`, `cordova platform rm ios`, then once again `cordova platform add android` and `cordova platform add ios`

Comment: Removing cordova-plugin-console was indeed the missing link; now all is set :-D. Thanks a lot!